# Using variables from one .py file in a loop in another .py file

Tags: python, loops, variables

I have a sql_data.py file that looks like this:

```
TABLE_A = '''Select * from Table_A;'''
TABLE_B = '''Select * from Table_B;'''
```

I have a main.py file where I want to loop over those variables and print the SQL.

```
import sql_data

tables = ['TABLE_A', 'TABLE_B']

# this doesn't work, but this is what I am looking for.  Something dynamic like below

for table in tables:
    print(SQL_DATA.[table])

# this works, but it's hard coding in the table name which I don't want

for table in tables:
    print(SQL_DATA.TABLE_A)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try `SQL_DATA.[table]`?

Comment: Yep, sorry.  Had typo in code.  I did try lowercase.  Doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the variable that you loop (aka, `table`) and `getattr` for getting attribute.

```
for table in tables:
    print(getattr(SQL_DATA, table))
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked.  I will accept when the timer lets me.  Thanks again